# Can every continuous, monotonic function be decomposed into concave and convex functions?

Tags: functions, continuity, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, nondecreasing function. Is it true that there exists some partition of the real line $-\infty = a_0 < a_1 < \dots < a_n < a_{n+1} = \infty$ such that on each interval $[a_i, a_{i+1}]$, $f$ is either concave or convex?

Intuitively, I think the answer should be "yes", because a continuous, nondecreasing function should look like a bunch of "s" shaped curves connected with each other. However, I'm not quite sure how to formalize this.

**Edit**: As mentioned by @tkf, the Cantor function is a counterexample. What are some sufficient conditions on $f$ that would make this true? E.g. absolute continuity? continuous differentiability?

Comment: I think the Devil's staircase would be a counterexample here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: @tkf Thanks! Would this statement be true if $f$ is also absolutely continuous, perhaps?

Comment: I am not sure.  Perhaps you should add the word 'absolutely' to your question, and mention that without this constraint one has counterexamples like the Cantor function.